# CRM for Mac that brings up records automatically when my iPhone rings

Tags: osx, ios, iphone-app, crm

Mac now supports transferring calls from iPhone to Mac. I am looking for a CRM that will use that functionality to search the CRM and bring up matching records of the caller's phone number when the phone rings.

Ideally it would prompt me to create a record if one wasn't found, and it would integrate with Gmail as well.

Answer (score 1):

- Phone Amego (http://www.sustworks.com/pa_guide/index.html), is mainly a telephony application that connects with a phone via bluetooth, it offers a very basic record keeping. Not very intuitive.


  It also integrates with Daylite (see below) which is a proper CRM.
- Daylite (https://www.marketcircle.com/) also offers a plugin called fone&text (https://www.marketcircle.com/help/article/fonetext-plugin/) and works with the Apple continuity (ie. transferring calls from iPhone to Mac) without the need for Phone Amego.


  It does not integrate with Gmail directly, but it does integrate nicely with Mac Mail and Mac Calendar which can be synced with Gmail and Google Calendar.


  It also offers some basic iPhone and iPad apps (no telephony or mail support in the iOS apps though).